# How can I get an entity edit path?

Tags: 7, entities

I made a module, and defined my custom entity there. I set the path for the administrative page using the following array.

```
'admin ui' => array(
  'path' => 'admin/structure/optimizations',
)
```

How can I get the edit path for one instance of my entity, for example admin/structure/optimizations/manage/2?

I don't think its a good idea to hard-code the path as with  `'admin/structure/optimizations/manage' . $entity->id`.
Is there any function to get the edit path for an entity?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [hook_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7)()

Here you can define paths and route variables to where they are needed.

For example:

```
function hook_menu() {
  $items['admin/structure/optimizations/manage/%'] = array(
      'title' => t('Your Page Title'),
      'page callback' => '_your_callback', // The callback that is building the page
      'page callback' => array(1), // This is the value from the % array key
      'access arguments' => array('administer users'), // A permission to require
      'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
}

function _your_callback($val) {

  //Access the % from the URL defined in hook menu using $val.

  ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `'uri callback'` key in [`hook_entity_info`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info/7)

> **uri callback:** The name of an implementation of
>   callback_entity_info_uri().

That function can be used to return the URL to the entity.

e.g:

- [`taxonomy_entity_info`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_entity_info/7)
- [`taxonomy_term_uri`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_uri/7)

Comment: That doesn't get you the edit path though...

Comment: @Clive While not the normal case, depending on the entity usage, the entity uri can potentially be the edit URL, as in the case of `commerce_product` and `commerce_product_uri` ( e.g: admin/commerce/products/12 returns the edit form)

Comment: I think the OP's after a generic solution to get the edit path for any entity (I don't think there's any such mechanism in core or the Entity module)

Comment: @Clive, yeah, I'm not aware of a generic `entity_edit_uri` function. Another option would be `hook_menu` similar to what the node module does with `node/%node/edit` and defining the path that way. It would be more of the 'hardcoded' approach referred to by OP for the edit URL.